# Golang communicate with LDAP

Tags: go, ldap

I'm trying to connect and authenticate a user to ldap with golang.

I'm using the [go-ldap-client](https://github.com/jtblin/go-ldap-client) with the following example code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/jtblin/go-ldap-client"
)

func main() {
    client := &ldap.LDAPClient{
        Base:         "dc=example,dc=com",
        Host:         "ldap.example.com",
        Port:         389,
        UseSSL:       false,
        BindDN:       "uid=readonlysuer,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com",
        BindPassword: "readonlypassword",
        UserFilter:   "(uid=%s)",
        GroupFilter: "(memberUid=%s)",
        Attributes:   []string{"givenName", "sn", "mail", "uid"},
    }
    # It is the responsibility of the caller to close the connection
    defer client.Close()

    ok, user, err := client.Authenticate("username", "password")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error authenticating user %s: %+v", "username", err)
    }
    if !ok {
        log.Fatalf("Authenticating failed for user %s", "username")
    }
    log.Printf("User: %+v", user)

    groups, err := client.GetGroupsOfUser("username")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error getting groups for user %s: %+v", "username", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Groups: %+v", groups) 
}
```

The dependency to gopkg.in/ldap.v2 is installed.

The **problem** is that I'm getting the following **error**:

```
2016/01/15 17:34:55 Error authenticating user username: LDAP Result Code 2 "Protocol Error": ldap: cannot StartTLS (unsupported extended operation)
exit status 1
```

Any hint about this error?

Comment: Just like the error says, the client library is trying to connect with StartTLS, which the server doesn't support. Is "github.com/jtblin/go-ldap-client" your code, or have you actually checked that someone's github repo with a single commit and no unit tests does what you expect?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/jtblin/go-ldap-client/blob/master/ldap-client.go#L39). So, I'd recommend to just use https://gopkg.in/ldap.v2 directly. Contrary to what the author of the wrapper library you're using wrote in their README, using a low-level LDAP library is not hard (I know from the experience) and provides you with a full control over what is being done. `go-ldap-client` is a works-in-my-environment product: if it works in yours, great; if it isn't -- you're on your own.

Comment: To provide more background, SSL/TLS can be used in LDAP on two levels: 1) the LDAP server might listen on a port which speaks SSL/TLS right away. That's what controlled by the `UseSSL` setting. 2) the LDAP server might accept a special protocol command, typically known as "STARTTLS" (it's also present in extensions to SMTP, and IMAP for instance). Should the server support this command, the client might use it to "upgrade" the current connection to an SSL/TLS tunnel and then restart exchanging LDAP traffic over it.

Comment: The author of `go-ldap-client` should check the error returned from attempting to use `STARTTLS` and supposedly fallback to not using SSL/TLS at all if the server rejected that command.  Now look closer: `go-ldap-client` explicitly disables validation of the server's certificate during the STARTTLS handshake, making it prone to MitM attacks. In reality it must be *your* decision, and you have to have full control over this. So, again, I'd recommend to just be explicit and use `gopkg.in/ldap.v2`.

Comment: @JimB: No it is not my code, but something that I have cloned

Comment: kostix:Thanks for your feedback. It really helpfull. Finally I overcome the error using the `ldap.v1` with the `go-ldap-client` but after your considerations I will implement my own with `ldap.v2`

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas how did you get this to work?  Or can anyone explain to me how to get the user's groups, using ldap.v2 ?

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but `readonlysuer` is probably supposed to be `readonlyuser`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, so let's try authentication using `github.com/go-ldap/ldap`. First you need to create a an `*ldap.Conn`. I suggest using TLS, if your LDAP server supports it:

```
// TLS, for testing purposes disable certificate verification, check https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config for further information.
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
l, err := ldap.DialTLS("tcp", "ldap.example.com:636", tlsConfig)

// No TLS, not recommended
l, err := ldap.Dial("tcp", "ldap.example.com:389")
```

Now you should have an active connection to your LDAP server. Using this connection you have to execute a bind:

```
err := l.Bind("user@test.com", "password")
if err != nil {
    // error in ldap bind
    log.Println(err)
}
// successful bind
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to use [go-guardian](https://github.com/shaj13/go-guardian) [LDAP strategy](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/shaj13/go-guardian@v1.0.0/auth/strategies/ldap?tab=doc)

A working example based on [Online LDAP Test Server](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/shaj13/go-guardian/auth/strategies/ldap"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    cfg := ldap.Config{
        BaseDN:       "dc=example,dc=com",
        BindDN:       "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com",
        Port:         "389",
        Host:         "ldap.forumsys.com",
        BindPassword: "password",
        Filter:       "(uid=%s)",
    }

    r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
    r.SetBasicAuth("tesla", "password")

    user, err := ldap.New(&cfg).Authenticate(r.Context(), r)
    fmt.Println(user, err)
}
```

Comment: I currently trying to use this package of yours in my project. However, instead of  *r http as parameters in Authenticator, would it be possible if autheticator will check username, pass pass from client form/request ? https://github.com/shaj13/go-guardian/issues/111

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by default the "SkipTLS" flag is not set in the aforementioned LDAP client. You need to explicitly set the parameter to false:

```
client := &ldap.LDAPClient{
        Base:         "dc=example,dc=com",
        Host:         "ldap.example.com",
        Port:         389,
        UseSSL:       false,
        BindDN:       "uid=readonlysuer,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com",
        BindPassword: "readonlypassword",
        UserFilter:   "(uid=%s)",
        GroupFilter:  "(memberUid=%s)",
        SkipTLS:      true,
        Attributes:   []string{"givenName", "sn", "mail", "uid"},
    }
```

I set the SkipTLS to true and it worked.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

In one line:

```
conn, err := ldap.DialTLS("tcp", ldapServer, &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
```

Comment: Please format your post properly and add some more details: How does that line solve the OP's problem, and where should it be applied?